# retrieving component from subfolders excluding some subfolders

Tags: 2013, core-service

I have a folder, which has subfolders and components.

For example, Main folder name as `030 Main`, which has subfolders with names:

- **`100 mango`**
- **`120 apple`**
- **`150 cake`**
- *`archive`*
- *`not used`*
- *`trash`*

There are also some components within `030 Main`.

Now I want to retrieve only the components which uses a specified schema from certain subfolders (in **bold** above):

- **`100 mango`**
- **`120 apple`**
- **`150 cake`**

I don't need any components from `archive`,`not used`,or `trash` nor the components within `030 Main`.

I tried something like below, first with a filter on the folder structure (I got tcm id's of `archive`,`not used`,`100 mango`,`120 apple`,`150 cake`,and `trash`).

Then I checked if the folder's tcm id matches `100 mango`, `120 apple`, or `150 cake`.

If this condition is true, I use a component filter to get all the components with specified schema.

> But here in `var id` I'm still getting the components present in `archive`, `not used` ,`trash`.

**Please suggest may be the second filtering part is not working.**

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
            {
                ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Folder },
              Recursive = true,
                BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Id
            };

        foreach (var id in client.GetListXml(folderUri, filter).Elements().ToList())
        {
            string so = id.Attribute("ID").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(so);
           if ((so == "tcm:229-38695-2") || (so == "tcm:229-149861-2")||(so == "tcm:229-149940-2")||(so =="tcm:229-149941-2")||(so == "tcm:229-149942-2")||(so =="tcm:229-149943-2")||(so =="tcm:229-149875-2"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i m in");
                OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter1 = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
                filter1.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component };
                filter1.ComponentTypes = new ComponentType[] { ComponentType.Normal };
                filter1.Recursive = true;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                string QuestionTitle = string.Empty;
                foreach (var idin in client.GetListXml(folderUri, filter1).Elements().ToList())
                {
                    string compSchema = idin.Attribute("SchemaId").Value;
                    string compId = idin.Attribute("ID").Value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line on code - `var idin in client.GetListXml(folderUri, filter1)`looks incorrect as it should be `var idin in client.GetListXml(so, filter1)` in my opinion to make any sense to your `if` clause

Comment: Also it seems the OR condition is put for all subfolders though the components have to be accessed from only three of them(guessing from number of checks).

Comment: Pankaj Thanks, it works. And thanks everyone for your valuable time.

Comment: If it works, would you mind accepting it as an answer for the betterment of the website. Also, it would be great if you think the answer is good for an upvote

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to use a different approach with the Search Query API from the Core Service.  Eric Huiza has written an excellent post about an example retrieving Components using a specific Schema.
http://erichuiza.blogspot.bg/2012/06/performing-search-queries-with-core.html

In addition, it is possible to pass in a 'SearchIn' parameter as specified in this answer, [Search in multiple folders via core service?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/276/search-in-multiple-folders-via-core-service)

Overall this code should perform faster and also be more flexible.  You might still need to apply a post-search filter, as in your code above, if you're not able to filter everything by the search query.