# Get component tcm id by component name in JAVA

Tags: core-service

Am new to cms tridion, I want to get the tcm id by component name and also I want to retrieve all the components in a given folder in java.

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: I am writing a stand alone java class to search a component by its name

Comment: Content Management back-end

Comment: Instead of adding additional information as comments, edit the question itself. Also, tag your question with the version of tridion you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Tridion community!

There are a number of APIs available in the system, each with a different purpose/usage scenarios.  If you're working on the CM side (purely content management), then explore the Core Services API, which is a WCF web service that you can bind to using any number of java clients that can consume WCF.  This would allow you to connect to the CMS, look at the components within a folder or search for a component by name.

If you're working with published content, I.e. Content. Delivery and/or the Web app itself, then explore the Content Delivery API, which comes in 2 flavors: a native java API or a Rest Odata API, both work off the published content database known as the Broker.

Start by reading the product docs and then branch out into numerous examples in community blogs and this site.  Note: most of the samples for Tridion 2011Sp1+ should be close to, if not the same as for Web 8.

Answer (score 1):

The coreservice is a WCF service, using Java is not the easiest - but definitely possible. I would recommend starting with reading:

- [Interacting with the Core Service from Java](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B2C3F336-0051-4576-8FFB-06A068CAA31F)
- [Core Service Java Client](http://mihaiconsulting.com/projects/core-service-java)

Now, finding a component is always easier if you know the TCM URI or the WebDAV Url of that object - just call client.Read("TcmUri or WebDAVUrl") and you're golden. If you don't know any of those, and only have the title, your 2nd best option is then to use Search. Here's another link that can help: [Search in multiple folders via core service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/276/search-in-multiple-folders-via-core-service).

This should help you get started, come back for more questions!

Comment: Thanks nuno :) this information helped me to get started. in my case I don't have tcmuri. I have component name. now I need to find out the tcm uri from the component name. trying hard from long time but no luck yet. can you help me here..

Comment: Have you tried using search, as I suggest?